# Easy Digital Downloads - How to use hooks correctly?

Tags: hooks

I’m using Easy Digital Downloads for my Wordpress webshop. After someone buy a item it needs to add data to the SQL database. I got this working by adding PHP code to shortcode-receipt.php. This is working correct but when I reload the receipt via browser or mail the PHP code will fire again.

I figured out that there was a hook in EDD, but i'm not sure how to use them. I figured out that the function needs to be added to functions.php.

file: /wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/functions.php

```
function pw_edd_on_complete_purchase( $payment_id ) {
## write data to the database ##
}
add_action( 'edd_complete_purchase', 'pw_edd_on_complete_purchase' );
```

But in what file do i place

`do_action( 'edd_complete_purchase', $payment_id );` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't put `do_action()` anywhere. The plugin runs that when that action occurs. You just need to hook into it with `add_action()`. The way hooks work is documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/).

If you're not sure when or how a plugin's own hooks, such as this one, are fired, then you'll need to contact the plugin developer, or consult its developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on top of what @Jacob Peattie said: the `do_action` is already in the EDD code somewhere, you don't have to add that part. That's the point that you your new function will get called *from*. Wordpress takes care of wiring up the two things for you, as per the docs link in Jacob's post.

As you wrote in your post, you need to add the `add_action` to your functions.php, or it can go in a plugin.